# Can't enable remote desktop on Windows 7 Professional N

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't enable remote desktop on Windows 7 Professional](https://superuser.com/questions/401553/cant-enable-remote-desktop-on-windows-7-professional)

What is wrong with this PC?
Windows 7 Professional N and all latest updates installed...

[image: system properties screenshot]

------------ADDED-----------------------

[sfc /scannow logs](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KwVQtjAR)