# Can't enable remote desktop on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop

What is wrong with this PC? Windows 7 Professional N and all latest updates installed..

i've  installed it from scratch last week. 
msdn iso en_windows_7_professional_n_with_sp1_x86_dvd_u_677328.iso

remote desktop services and remote desktop configuration services are started and running

this is the registry entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server]
"RCDependentServices"=hex(7):43,00,65,00,72,00,74,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,70,00,\
  53,00,76,00,63,00,00,00,53,00,65,00,73,00,73,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,45,00,6e,\
  00,76,00,00,00,00,00
"NotificationTimeOut"=dword:00000000
"SnapshotMonitors"="1"
"ProductVersion"="5.1"
"AllowRemoteRPC"=dword:00000000
"DelayConMgrTimeout"=dword:00000000
"fDenyTSConnections"=dword:00000000
"StartRCM"=dword:00000000
"TSAdvertise"=dword:00000000
"DeleteTempDirsOnExit"=dword:00000001
"fSingleSessionPerUser"=dword:00000000
"PerSessionTempDir"=dword:00000000
"TSUserEnabled"=dword:00000000
"InstanceID"="e7e3d8d1-5b4f-4e66-ae61-4e900f9"
```

sfc /scannow did not find any integrity violations.

[image: system properties screenshot]

Comment: This is weird, since Win 7 Pro has RDP host. Try sfc /scannow in command prompt. You might be missing some files.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/d3d63b47-e758-481d-bc6e-cf69a9413f37

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i'm running it and i'll post results.

Comment: Sadly: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Has the computer previously been in a domain where the domain admins have pushed some gpo:s on their clients disabling the rdp host?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund no, i've installed it from scratch last week. msdn iso en_windows_7_professional_n_with_sp1_x86_dvd_u_677328.iso

Comment: wow no one can help me???

Comment: is the machine in a domain?  could remote desktop be disabled by group policy?

Comment: no, there has never been

Comment: @giammin - Why did you go with that particular version of Windows 7 instead of the normal Professional version?  In particular why the `N` version?

Comment: @Ramhound this problem affects all versions (professional, ultimate, enterprise) not only the N version. Anyway N version means that windows media player is not preinstalled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution, but I found out that it is due to SP1 being installed. Some people with the same problem resolved it by removing SP1.

[Remote Desktop doesn't work after upgrade to SP1 - Windows 7 Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/149496-remote-desktop-doesnt-work-after-upgrade-sp1.html)